# DB values inconsistently being displayed in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

So I made a scaffold for a model called Club and then removed a column called `:title` and added one called `:name`. I then edited the route to have `only: [:index, :show]`. I went into the controller code and made it this:

```
before_action :set_club, only: [:show]

  # GET /clubs
  # GET /clubs.json
  def index
    @social = Club.where tag: "Social"
  end

  # GET /clubs/1
  # GET /clubs/1.json
  def show
  end
```

I then seeded the database as such:

```
Club.create([{ name: 'Club 1' }, {role: 'officer'}, {tag: 'Social'}, {description: 'asd'}])
Club.create([{ name: 'Club 2' }, {role: 'member'}, {tag: 'Social'}, {description: 'efg'}])
```

and set the views to be:

```
<h2>SOCIAL</h2>    
<% @social.each do |project| %>    
  <div class="club">    
    Project: <%= project.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<strong>name:</strong>
<%= @club.name %>

<strong>Description:</strong>
<%= @club.description %>

<strong>Role:</strong>
<%= @club.role %>

<strong>Tag:</strong>
<%= @club.tag %>

<br />
<%= link_to 'Back', clubs_path %>
<br />
```

However, when rendered, the values of name, tag, etc. don't consistently show up.

This are screens shots from /clubs, /clubs/1, and /clubs/2 in order:

[image: index resource]

[image: show resource 1]

[image: show resource 2]

It seems some of the fields just don't render consistently. I get zero names on the index route, and only one of them shows a name in the show route. Any idea what is causing this? It seems to be finding both clubs, because it is printing "Project:" twice.

PS: My schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180630182744) do    
  create_table "clubs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "description"
    t.string "tag"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "role"
  end
end
```

EDIT: The pre_action is as follows:

```
def set_club
  @club = Club.find(params[:id])
end
```

UPDATE: It seems to be reading each field as it's own database entry. With the seed shown above, I'm actually able to go through `clubs/1` through `8` each with one field filled in...

Comment: You seem to have declared nowhere the `@club` instance variable ... In your index view you can add `@clubs = Club.all` and iterate through each the same way you do for social / project. `@clubs.each do ...`

Comment: If the view corresponding to the second bit is the view of show action, then declare club there : `def show / @club = Club.find(params[:id] / end`

Comment: The long term goal was to separate them out by the tag, Social, Academic, etc. And then display them in groups. In my view I never reference @club, and is there a reason I can't name my instance variables whatever I please? Also, the word project may be confusing, that should really be "club" or "group"

Comment: Also, there's a pre action that sets @club, as made default by the scaffold: `def set_club
      @club = Club.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: Your two pieces of views that are separate by the word "and", are they from the same view `index.html.erb` or are they 2 different views ?

Comment: index and show respectively

Comment: ok then you type the wrong address. you say the resulting view are from `/clubs, /clubs/1, and /clubs/2` try `/clubs, /club/1, and /club/2` instead

Comment: No, well maybe that's what they should be, but when I but `http://localhost:3000/clubs/1` into my url I get that second photo and club/1 errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174100/discussion-between-maxence-and-riley-shaw).

Answer (score 0):

My seed.rb was setup wrong, I was passing in an array of hashes instead of a single hash in the array. Corrected it to:

```
Club.create([{ name: 'Club 1', role: 'officer', tag: 'Social', description: 'asd'}])
Club.create([{ name: 'Club 2', role: 'member', tag: 'Social', description: 'efg'}])
```

Notice how there is one hash containing all the clubs fields.

Comment: This is still an array of hashes. :)

Comment: In case my solution was confusing, this is an array of hash. As in singular. The broken code had a hash for each column in the DB, where as this is a single hash, with all the fields, in an array. If I did the creates as one `Club.create` with each club in it, it would be an array of two hashes and that would be an array of hashes that would work too, I believe

Comment: I got how the two arrays were different. I just wanted to correct the terminology. :)